# What is the Reactor (projectreactor.io) backlog?

Tags: java, spring, reactor, project-reactor

Many [Reactor](https://projectreactor.io/) Dispatchers let you specify the "backlog", e.g.:

[`SingleThreadDispatcher(int backlog)`](https://projectreactor.io/old/api/reactor/core/dispatch/SingleThreadDispatcher.html#SingleThreadDispatcher-int-)

[`ThreadPoolExecutorDispatcher(int poolSize, int backlog)`](https://projectreactor.io/old/api/reactor/core/dispatch/ThreadPoolExecutorDispatcher.html#ThreadPoolExecutorDispatcher-int-int-)

I found [some documentation](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-samples/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/reactor/default.properties) saying:

```
reactor.dispatchers.threadPoolExecutor.type = threadPoolExecutor
reactor.dispatchers.threadPoolExecutor.size = 0
# Backlog is how many Task objects to warm up internally
reactor.dispatchers.threadPoolExecutor.backlog = 1024
```

Can someone help me understand what this means and what a sensible value might be?

Comment: There seems to be no Dispatchers in current release (3.0.4)

Comment: v3 was released a few months after I posted this question. It looks like a major rewrite and lacks any migration documentation. We dropped the project. This question still stands for anyone using v1 or v2 of the project.